# Open .xls/.xlsx file through web browser and make it editable for the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, web, oledb

**Specification**

- using .Net 3.5/4.0 framework
- Web Application C#
- Machine don't have MS Office install

**Problem:**
 Need to open excel file report from web browser for the user to edit the report and save the update on the excel file. (is it possible? for the fact that the machine don't have a MS office install).

**By Code:** I can only read the file and display it through grid but cannot edit.

```
public void LoadExceltotheGrid()
{
    string connectionString = "";
    string fileLocation = MapPath("FileMe20140107.xlsx");
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileLocation);
    if (fileExtension == ".xls")
    {
        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
        fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
    {
        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
        fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();
    con.Open();
    DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
    dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
    GridView1.DataSource = dtExcelRecords;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You should be able to embed Office 365's Excel Web App in your own website, but I believe the xlsx has to be stored in the cloud (SkyDrive/Office365/Sharepoint Online). Reinventing Excel is going to prove extremely difficult to say the least

Comment: the application was already exist and widely used. I can't do much, my task is limited only on creating a function that will call the excel file and view it through web, and make it editable.

Comment: You've been tasked with an impossible requirement then.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complicated task to be honest - the Office format is so complicated, that it is not easily writeable. This is especially true for the xls format - this is next to impossible to read / write natively. There are third party tools like Aspose.Cells which can do it, but you have to pay a license fee.

Your method via OLedb works for simple use cases, but even simple changes to the format structure will throw it of , also it's slow. So it seems like a solution, but it's a half-assed solution at best which will cause maintenance grid without end.

The xlsx format is much easier to read / write so if you can drop support for xls files, you have much better chances to work with that format. The format is called "Office open xml" , there is a sdk from Microsoft for it. This SDK is not very user friendly and very bare-bones, so I would recommend a library like EPPLUS to read / write the files. It is extremely easy, fast and costs nothing. It even has methods to convert from / to datatables.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplished my task using SkyDrive. [Working with Microsoft OneDrive folders and files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx#file_links)

- upload first the file in the SkyDrive(given i already had an account).
- get the link of the file and embed it to the page.